# How does a cursor refer to deleted rows?

Tags: android, sqlite

When I get a Cursor back from a sqlite DB query in Android it seems to contain a fixed number of rows that does not change regardless of what happens to the DB. If, for example, some of the rows are deleted while the Cursor is open I can still reference rows that have been deleted. This is nice, but how does it work?

One guess might be that sqlite knows I have a Cursor that is pointing to that row and so keeps a copy of the old data around. But what if I had a million rows, deleted them and replaced them with a million different rows, seems like a lot of data to cache!

**UPDATE:**

I am now thinking that this caching we see in Android isn't really bullet-proof and isn't part of SQLite. I created a test which builds a database with 1,000,000 rows in it, then I queried the db printed out some results and left the cursor open, next I deleted half the rows, finally I tried to access the cursor that I left open and the result is a crash:

```
04-05 18:17:16.141 E/AndroidRuntime(19655): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
04-05 18:17:16.141 E/AndroidRuntime(19655):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
04-05 18:17:16.141 E/AndroidRuntime(19655):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:507)
04-05 18:17:16.141 E/AndroidRuntime(19655):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
04-05 18:17:16.141 E/AndroidRuntime(19655):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:220)
04-05 18:17:16.141 E/AndroidRuntime(19655):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
04-05 18:17:16.141 E/AndroidRuntime(19655):     at com.jacob.DirectDbActivity$4.run(DirectDbActivity.java:88)
```

This seems like a bug in Android, since most databases are small the cache window can hold all the results but in large databases this is going to hit you.

Comment: I found this page (http://www.sqlite.org/malloc.html) that says "SQLite uses dynamic memory allocation ... to hold the results of queries." This seems to indicate that the results are cached in memory, although there are obviously limits if you have an extremely large result set, I am guessing a temporary file must be created at some point if the cache gets too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last I checked, a cursor is a snapshot of the database based on the SQL that created it. Much like a Data set. If you change the database the cursors may not know that their snapshot is old. You can perform a re-query on the cursor to get fresh data based on the original SQL that created the cursor.

Comment: I think you are correct but I am curious if there is more complete documentation on this somewhere.

Comment: From the SQLiteDatabase documentation: A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry. Note that Cursors are not synchronized, see the documentation for more details.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation that is specific on this? I'd like a little more info, is there a temporary file written to the file system? Seems like this would be a big penalty of doing queries that contain many rows.