# Do SQLite queries that return large result sets take more time?

Tags: sqlite

When performing a SQLite query does the size of the returned data set affect how long the query takes? Lets assume for this question that I don't actually access any of the data in the result, I just want to know if the query itself takes longer. Lets also assume that I am simply selecting all rows and have no WHERE or ORDER BY clauses.

For example if I have two tables A and B. Let says table A has a million rows and table B has 10 rows and that both tables have the same number and types of columns. Will selecting all rows in table A take longer than selecting all rows in table B?

This is a follow up to my question [How does a cursor refer to deleted rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367905/how-does-a-cursor-refer-to-deleted-rows). I am guessing that if a during the query SQLite makes a copy of the data then queries that return large data sets may take longer, unless there is an optimization that only copies the query result data if there is a change to the data in the db while the query is still alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on some details, yes, a query may take different amounts of time.

Example: I have a table with some 20k entries. I do a GLOB search that must try every line, with a LIMIT. If the LIMIT is met, the query can stop early. If not, it must go through the entire table (or JOIN). So searches with too many results return quicker than searches with only a few results.

If the query must run through the same amount of data, I don't expect there is a significant difference between a smaller and larger amount of selected rows. There will probably be IO cost, of course.

Comment: I have clarified my question, I am interested only in situations where I select all rows from a single table, no WHERE, ORDER BY, LIMIT, or JOIN clauses.

Comment: Ok. I would say the answer is the same. Running through more rows in table A will take longer. An index may make that step go away. If you select all, I would expect the rows to come out as fast as IO (plus overhead) allows. More data at same rate will take longer.